# Infinity - Infinity = NaN?

Tags: javascript, math

Any number minus itself should be `0`, correct?

```
3 - 3 === 0
```

Then why

```
Infinity - Infinity === NaN
```

Because `typeof Infinity` is `'number'`:

Comment: `Infinity` is not a specific number.

Comment: You're assuming that all infinities are equal. But some are more equal than others.

Comment: That is not allowed in math, similarly to doing `0^0`, which is also not allowed.

Comment: @Jus12 `0^0` is _defined_ as `1`

Comment: @Jus12 who said 0^0 = 1?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan `Math.pow(0, 0) === 1`.

Comment: then u should open another question why on earth Math.pow gives us such wrong answer.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan [it's actually an accepted workaround](http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.0.to.0.power.html). Formally it's 'indeterminate' but that doesn't exist in floating point space, a value that can represent multiple real values is neither infinite nor NaN. For all practical purposes `1` is the commonly accepted alternative that fits all real world applications.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didnt know it before. @nielskeurentjes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As we know that, difference between two numbers can be calculated like this

```
a - b = a + (-b)
```

JavaScript uses this to find the difference between two values. Quoting from [Applying the Additive Operators to Numbers section from ECMA 5.1 Specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.3),

> The - operator performs subtraction when applied to two operands of numeric type, producing the difference of its operands; the left operand is the minuend and the right operand is the subtrahend. Given numeric operands a and b, it is always the case that a–b produces the same result as a +(–b).

So, when you do

```
Infinity - Infinity
```

it is evaluated as

```
Infinity + (-Infinity)
```

In JavaScript, they both are different Objects. Quoting from [The Number Type section of ECMA 5.1 Specification](http://es5.github.io/#x8.5),

> There are two other special values, called **positive Infinity** and **negative Infinity**. For brevity, these values are also referred to for expository purposes by the symbols `+∞` and `−∞`, respectively. (Note that these two infinite Number values are produced by the program expressions `+Infinity` (or simply `Infinity`) and `-Infinity`.)

Again, quoting from [Applying the Additive Operators to Numbers section from ECMA 5.1 Specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.3)

> - If either operand is `NaN`, the result is `NaN`.
> - **The sum of two infinities of opposite sign is `NaN`**.
> - The sum of two infinities of the same sign is the infinity of that sign.
> - ...

That is why the result is `NaN`.

Comment: @Xero Not just Javascript. Everything that uses native floating-point.

Answer (score 8):

For any number `x`, we should have `x + 1 - x == 1`, right? Well,

```
Infinity + 1 == Infinity
```

So what should `Infinity + 1 - Infinity` be? Is it `1`? Then we have `Infinity - Infinity == 1`, which seems weird and arbitrary.

There is no infinity in the real numbers. There is an infinity in floating-point because it's convenient for some numerical algorithms to get a result when you do things like `1 / 0`, but floating-point infinity cannot have all the nice properties you would like a number to have. In particular, there's no sensible number to return for `Infinity - Infinity`, so we get `NaN`.

Comment: Infinity is not a number. x + 1 - x == 1 is valid only for the numbers, not for infinity.

Answer (score 4):

The special number value `Infinity` encapsulates a *concept*.

It's meant for comparisons. By definition you can't do any arithmetic with it.

Assume a password expiry value. If you check the box "never expire", you could set the internal value to `Infinity`. Any comparison `actualDate < expiryDate` would evaluate to `true` (except of course when `actualDate` is `Infinity` itself).

That's a lot better than defining the "no `expiryDate`" state as an arbitrary value like `0` or `-1` or `null` or `undefined`, where you have to maintain and remember what that value conceptually means in your application, introducing a new potential bug in every line where a date comparison happens.

Answer (score 3):

**Infinity is not a Number. Its an idea, its a concept.** Spend around 8 min to understand what is infinity from one of my favorite YouTube channels (Numberphile):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elvOZm0d4H0

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Infinity is not a number.

Comment: According to JavaScript, it is. `typeof Infinity` is in fact `number`

Comment: @Xero: And according to Javascript, `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`.

Comment: @user2357112 No, that's a necessary consequence of IEEE 754 floating point number representation, not "according to JavaScript".

Comment: @Jordan `Infinity` is a number. It's just not a number you can do calculations with.

Comment: @Tomalak I feel very silly now. I should say the reason NaN is true, is because of what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Infinity-Infinity is unknown because Infinity is endless, but it is Infinity-Infinity so, it might be 0 or Infinity